# change color when axios data "status: 1"

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, axios

I want to write a function that lets me change the background color of my button, when the data in my axios api is equal to 1
the data in array is like this:

```
[{
    "id": 189,
    "ref_num": "12345678",
    "status": 1,
    "date": 1627134707,
    "amount": "8660000"
},]
```

and the code I want to write is for changing the bg color of button when `status === "1"`
I've already wrote a function for axios.get the data and inside of it, made an if statement:

```
async getTransactions() {
  const response = await this.$store.dispatch("axiosGet", {url: '/transaction/list'})
  if (response.status === 'error') return
  this.transactList = response.data.data
  if (response.data.data.status === '1') return document.getElementById('status').style.backgroundColor = "red!important";
  console.log(response.data.data)
},
```

it console.logs the data inside of response.data.data but the if statement doesn't work.
can anyone help with that please?
also, I get an "undefined" log for `response.data.data.status`

Comment: How do you render `transactList` in the template?

Comment: `async axiosGet({dispatch}, {url}) {
            dispatch('checkAuth')
            let result
            await axios.get(url)
                .then(res => {
                    result = {message: 'success', data: res}
                }).catch(err => {
                    console.log(err)
                    result = {message: 'success', data: err}
                })
            return result
        }`
in store

Answer (score 1):

I think, the problem is in the ***if*** condition. You are checking for string data, but in the response you getting integer data.
use  `if (response.data.data.status === 1)` , instead of `if (response.data.data.status === '1')`. Remove the single quote.
Or, you can use `==` instead of `===`.

Comment: I've found out that there's a problem with `response.data.data.status`. it gives me back undefined

Comment: Since `response.data.data` is an array, you'll need to loop through the array.